# Getting "object expected" error when trying to call a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

The window.alert function does not work and the debugger in internet explorer highlights

```
registerForm()
```

in the onclick event on line 15 and gives the error "Object Expected".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javscript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
function registerForm() {
window.alert("Function is working");
}
/* ]]> */
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<p><input type="button" value="Register" onclick="registerForm();" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
</body>
```

Comment: Try with just `alert`, no "window."

Comment: @elclanrs: `alert === window.alert`

Comment: I know, but you're never wrong to assume it could be an IE bug xD. Who knows, maybe it changes the context of `window` for some unknown reason. Seems like this is not the case by looking at the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
<script type="text/javscript">
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript"> //you missed "a" in script tag
```

Comment: Better yet, get rid of `type="text/javascript"` entirely. Also get rid of the CDATA stuff. Don't need any of that.

Comment: Thanks Sudhir. I know it's not technically necessary to include the CDATA stuff and such but I always include it anyways so that it will pass through the w3c validator.

Comment: No, you don't need CDATA or type="text/javascript" to pass the validator. Try it and see. I took both of those out of your page and the only two validation errors were the extra `</body>` at the end, and the empty `action=""` attribute. Fix those and you're golden.

Comment: Isn't specifying "text/javascript" more efficient for the browser though?